# How to remove executable path error

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am getting error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist:

However I have used `system.setproperty` command but still getting error on chrome.

Comment: Put code piece on how are you trying to the set the property.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Selenium Java/Standalone version are you using? In  Selenium 3.0.1 you have to specify the path of the driver. For that you need to download the Chrome driver and save in C:\foldername then to initialize Chrome driver in Windows you need to do this:

`System.setproperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\\foldername\\chromedriver.exe"); 
Webdriver driver=new ChromeDriver ();`

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: @akash gupta did you try out the option I mentioned?

Comment: @akashgupta If your question got answered please Accept it as a Solution . Else feel free to ask any issue you are facing.